# PHP MySQL insert statement won't insert data into my database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert some data into my database with this code:

```
        $username = $_SESSION['user'];
        $naslov = $_POST['naslov'];//name
        $geslo = $_POST['geslo'];//password
        $vsebina = $_POST['vsebina'];//description

        if (trim($_POST['naslov'])=="" || $_POST['geslo']=="" || $_POST['vsebina']==""){
        $status = "<div class='alert-danger'>Fields are empty</div>";
           }
     else{
        $link = open_database_connection();

        echo $username;
        echo $naslov;
        echo $geslo;
        echo $vsebina;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO projects (name, password, description, username) VALUES ('$naslov','$geslo','$vsebina','$username')";
         mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        close_database_connection($link);
        $status = "<div class='alert-success'>Vic je bil dodan.</div>";
        }
```

The echo show the values i am putting into the forms, the SQL does not show any errors it just doesn't insert the values into the table.

Comment: echo mysqli_error($link);

Comment: You are using `close_database_connection` instead of `mysqli_close($link)`, is there maybe more fancy stuff that can break the code. What does `open_database_connection()` really do? Did the  `open_database_connection()` also select the right Database?

Comment: Show more relevant code! Show database table structure? Use what @Farkie says. By the way: Do you really want to save PASSWORDS plain into the Database?

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). This can also fix any pesky quoting issues that may be cropping up.

Comment: The problem was that i accidentally put a space in my db name column. echo mysql_error($ink); show me the problem.
i will add protection to the code. striptags, trimtags and and the password will be encriped with sha1.

Answer (score 0):

check if form method is POST  if its not then change the code to

```
     $username = $_SESSION['user'];
    $naslov = $_GET['naslov'];//name
    $geslo = $_GET['geslo'];//password
    $vsebina = $_GET['vsebina'];//description

    if (trim($_GET['naslov'])=="" || $_GET['geslo']=="" || $_GET['vsebina']==""){
    $status = "<div class='alert-danger'>Fields are empty</div>";
       }
 else{
    $link = open_database_connection();

    echo $username;
    echo $naslov;
    echo $geslo;
    echo $vsebina;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO projects (name, password, description, username) VALUES ('$naslov','$geslo','$vsebina','$username')";
     mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    close_database_connection($link);
    $status = "<div class='alert-success'>Vic je bil dodan.</div>";
    }
```